# manipulating the screen from subclass

Tags: java, android

So I have created an android app and things are working alright.

In my main class I do a

```
new Game();
```

Now from the constructor of the game object I try and manipulate the screen, but it does not seem to do anything. Is it even possible?

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.board);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is your "main" class ? You're not supposed to instanciate activities directly, but use intents instead.

Comment: thanks :) that made me able to solve the problem :), you can put it as an answer :)

Comment: You should probably go through the Hello Android tutorials to understand how the framework works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to instanciate activities directly, but use intents instead.